# RuntimeError: CUDA error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device with 3090 cuda11.3 torch10.1

Tags: pytorch, gpu

Hi I am trying to run the evaluation code on an RTX 3090, but encountered the following issue:

```
[13.73019    90.45654    -0.80213207  0.57002985]
 [12.367015   90.64196     1.0528708   0.56709075]
 [12.335012   90.66197    -0.82074624  0.5729689 ]]
Error!

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 201, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 197, in main
    eval_single_ckpt(model, test_loader, args, eval_output_dir, logger, epoch_id, dist_test=dist_test)
  File "test.py", line 63, in eval_single_ckpt
    eval_utils.eval_one_epoch(
  File "/workspace/Dual-Radar/tools/eval_utils/eval_utils.py", line 199, in eval_one_epoch
    pred_dicts, ret_dict = model(batch_dict)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/DR/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1102, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/workspace/Dual-Radar/tools/../pcdet/models/detectors/pointpillar.py", line 21, in forward
    pred_dicts, recall_dicts = self.post_processing(batch_dict)
  File "/workspace/Dual-Radar/tools/../pcdet/models/detectors/detector3d_template.py", line 273, in post_processing
    recall_dict = self.generate_recall_record(
  File "/workspace/Dual-Radar/tools/../pcdet/models/detectors/detector3d_template.py", line 310, in generate_recall_record
    iou3d_rcnn = iou3d_nms_utils.boxes_iou3d_gpu(box_preds[:, 0:7], cur_gt[:, 0:7])
  File "/workspace/Dual-Radar/tools/../pcdet/ops/iou3d_nms/iou3d_nms_utils.py", line 69, in boxes_iou3d_gpu
    max_of_min = torch.max(boxes_a_height_min, boxes_b_height_min)
RuntimeError: CUDA error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device
eval:   0%|
```

I run this code:

```
import torch
import sys
print('A', sys.version)
print('B', torch.__version__)
print('C', torch.cuda.is_available())
print('D', torch.backends.cudnn.enabled)
device = torch.device('cuda')
print('E', torch.cuda.get_device_properties(device))
print('F', torch.tensor([1.0, 2.0]).cuda())
```

and get:

```
A 3.8.16 (default, Jun 12 2023, 18:09:05)
[GCC 11.2.0]
B 1.10.1+cu113
C True
D True
E _CudaDeviceProperties(name='NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090', major=8, minor=6, total_memory=24259MB, multi_processor_count=82)
F tensor([1., 2.], device='cuda:0')
```

My CUDA version is 11.3, and PyTorch is 1.10.1+cu113.I have tried different versions of PyTorch, such as 1.9.0, 1.11.0, and 1.10.0, but none of them worked.From the output, it appears that my GPU and CUDA are running fine, but the evaluation process still encounters errors. Could it be that the matrices are too large? How can I solve it?

Comment: The version of PyTorch you are trying to use has been built without support for your GPU architecture. You need a different build of PyTorch which includes Compute Capability 8.6 binary support

Comment: hi thanks for your reply.But how can I get the pythorch version which includes Compute Capability 8.6 binary support? the torch I installed is suitable for cuda11.3, and cuda11.3 is suitable for 3090

Comment: I don't know that answer to that, sorry

Comment: I solved the problem by rebuilding the conda environment and Install torch separately and comment out the installation requirements related to cuda and torch in the requirements.

Comment: So please add your solution as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by rebuilding the conda environment and Install torch separately and comment out the installation requirements related to cuda and torch in the requirements